# Icon in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I used the following code:

`JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(someImage));`

I don't get it.. sometimes the image appears when I run the code and sometimes not.. I'm not always getting the same output. Anyone can explain why this could happen?!

Comment: show how you construct your gui. How do you get your image?

Comment: `jLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(someImage));`

Comment: Code looks ok, you should check `someImage`. What is it (image, string, bytes, ...) and how do you get it?

Comment: Is it possible, you're setting the frame visible too early?

Comment: @Samy is right. Check `someImage`. It should be the path to the image.

Comment: OP said the the image shows up sometimes. I don't think its a path problem.

Comment: peeskillet you are right.. I set the visibility too early.. thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Without more code for context it's hard to know for sure, but whenever I hear about a Swing problem that *sometimes* works, I tend to suspect threading problems; if your GUI is, say, a dialog that is not being built on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) then this sort of randomness is common. If you are not sure about your threading, put this at the top of your method where this code is being executed:

```
System.out.println(String.format("This code %s running on the Event Dispatch Thread.", (javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() ? "IS" : "IS NOT"));
```

and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example for you with `JLabel` and `Icon`, examine that :

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    public Example() {
        URL resource = getClass().getResource("image.png");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resource);
        JLabel l = new JLabel(icon);
        add(l);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new Example();
    }

}
```

`image.png` is my image, that is placed in the same folder as the class.